# Rails remote conflicts with bootstrap remote modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm having a problem with Twitter bootstrap & Rails data-remote link.

I load the modal content with `data-remote="/path/to/data"`. Everything works as I want BUT create two requests.

```
= link_to '#myModal', 'Click here', data: {toggle: 'modal', remote: '/path'}
```

The first is rails data-reomte who makes a request to the page I'm at and after that bootstrap makes his requets and the modal is shown.

Is there any way I can turn of rails remote on specified links or is it actually another problem?

Comment: Maybe some context is missing but why would you want to turn off your remote if that is loading the content of your modal? The request from bootstrap is only used to show the modal I believe and is not _really_ a http request.

Comment: Bootstrap is loading the content via data-remote and rails is loading a get request. I only want the modal to be loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Bootstrap doc on Modal: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

> if you're using the data api, you may alternatively use the href tag to specify the remote source. An example of this is shown below:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">click me</a>
```

So, your request can be fulfilled by disable Rails UJS data api and use Bootstrap's. Like this

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal" 
data-remote="false">click me</a>
```

In your case. The server side code

```
= link_to 'Click here', '/path_for_bootstrap',
    data: {toggle: 'modal', remote: false, target: "#myModal"}
```

**Update** Or better, no need to define `remote` at all because nobody need it, either Bootstrap or UJS!

```
= link_to 'Click here', '/path_for_bootstrap',
    data: {toggle: 'modal', target: "#myModal"}
```

Comment: Ahh, if I've removed the remote: false it works and only one request is create. Thank you!!

Comment: @sandelius, aha, yes :) Actually you don't need to define `remote` in this case at all.

Comment: Hm .. I wanted to create "no-javascript client" compatible code .. Bootstrap allows us to set href for browsers with no JS (or spiders) and set data-remote for browsers with JS support.

Comment: Is there a solution for this or should we write no-compatible code? :(